# What is the default gitlab-ci image?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've looked at the [gitlab docker documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) but I cannot find it, what is the default gitlab-ci docker image?

(I'm not setting `default:image:`)

Comment: Isn't the image's name printed on the first lines of the execution log?

Comment: Are you asking about gitlab.com shared runners ? If so the answer is here (ruby:3.1): https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html#saas-runners-on-linux-settings

Comment: both good points thanks, I was missing that. You can answer below if you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So taking from the comments, the image is shown at start of build and for the curious around gitlab.com shared runners there's details on gitlab site for the [saas_runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html#saas-runners-on-linux-settings)

For linux shared runners the default image at time of writing is `ruby:3.1`

For on premise (own runners), the default image is specified at time of registering the runner.